# Zabbix server docker does not connect to zabbix agent and vice versa

Tags: docker, docker-compose, zabbix

This is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest'
    container_name: pooyesh-zookeeper
    ports: 
      - 2181:2181
    env_file: 
      - zookeeper.env  
  kafka:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest'
    container_name: pooyesh-kafka
    env_file:
      - kafka.env
    ports: 
      - 9093:9093
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: pooyesh-postgres
    env_file: 
      - postgres.env
    ports:
      - 5342:5432
    volumes: 
      - pooyesh-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    
  zabbix-server:
    image: 'zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql:latest'
    container_name: pooyesh-zabbix-server
    env_file: 
      - zabbix-server.env
    ports: 
      - 10051:10051
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
  zabbix-frontend:
    image: 'zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql:latest'
    container_name: pooyesh-zabbix-frontend
    env_file: 
      - zabbix-frontend.env
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
    depends_on:
      - zabbix-server
      - postgres
  zabbix-agent:   # Zabbix agent service that tracks usage and send to zabbix server
    image: zabbix/zabbix-agent:latest
    container_name: pooyesh-zabbix-agent
    privileged: true   #access mode for allowing resource access
    environment:
      - ZBX_SERVER_HOST=zabbix-server #the IP/Dns of Zabbix server
    volumes:
      - pooyesh-zabbix-agent:/etc/zabbix/

volumes: 
  pooyesh-postgres:
  pooyesh-zabbix-agent:
  pooyesy-zabbix-server:
```

And also these are their related env files:

**postgres.env**

```
POSTGRES_USER=pooyesh
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=2110320982
POSTGRES_DB=pooyesh
```

**zabbix-server.env**

```
DB_SERVER_HOST=postgres
DB_SERVER_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=pooyesh
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=2110320982
POSTGRES_DB=pooyesh
ZBX_TIMEOUT=10
```

**zabbix-frontend.env**

```
DB_SERVER_HOST=postgres
DB_SERVER_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=pooyesh
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=2110320982
POSTGRES_DB=pooyesh
ZBX_SERVER_HOST=zabbix-server
ZBX_SERVER_PORT=10051
```

When I run the docker-compose file, this is the log which I get from the `pooyesh-zabbix-server` container:

```
213:20210929:180535.655 cannot send list of active checks to "172.18.0.3": host [9de9d2980576] not found
198:20210929:182416.233 item "Zabbix server:vfs.fs.size[/,pused]" became not supported: Value of type "string" is not suitable for value type "Numeric (unsigned)". Value "92.887666"
```

And also this is the log which I get from the `pooyesh-zabbix-agent` container:

```
76:20210929:194155.572 active check configuration update from [zabbix-server:10051] started to fail (cannot resolve [zabbix-server])
    76:20210929:194255.588 active check configuration update from [zabbix-server:10051] is working again
    76:20210929:194255.588 no active checks on server [zabbix-server:10051]: host [23d448ba463e] not found
```

Maybe it is useful to say that I have telnet from each of these two containers to the other one. for example on the `pooyesh-zabbix-server` I have telnet `telnet zabbix-agent 10050`

All of these containers are in the same docker-compose network and I don't know what is wrong.
I also put `zabbix-server` config file [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/3a1823c5) and `zabbix-agent` config file [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/e498105e)

Answer (score 4):

I finally can resolve my problem.
`zabbix-agent` has an environment variable named `ZBX_HOSTNAME` which should be the name of the hostname in the zabbix web hosts tab. in my case it was `Zabbix server`. So when I add `ZBX_HOSTNAME=Zabbix server` to environment variables of my `zabbix-agent` and depends on it to the `zabbix-server` everything is good.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to update in Zabbix the host IP with the one of it's Docker container.