# docker container zabbix server - no active checks on server host not found

Tags: docker, containers, zabbix, dockerhub

I want to use zabbix monitor with separate docker container,
so, actually i have 4 containers :

```
zabbix-server-mysql using 10051 port 
zabbix-web-nginx-mysql using 8080 port (that's work) 
zabbix-java-gateway using 10052 port
mysql-server using 3306 port
```

zabbix-server is available on the interface zabbix and using server (vps) address and 10050 port

for exemple 193.71.58.25:10050

[image]

this is my zabbix-agent2.conf configuration using PSK

```
Server=172.17.0.4 --> zabbix-server-mysql IPAddress
ServerActive=172.17.0.4
Hostname=cb6b283d07ce --> Hostname of zabbix-server-mysql container
TLSConnect=psk
TLSAccept=psk
TLSPSKIdentity=PSK 100
TLSPSKFile=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd2.psk
```

Now i have this error on the zabbix-agent2.log :

```
13:38:16.009644 [101] no active checks on server [172.17.0.4:10051]: host [cb6b283d07ce] not found
```

And looking at the

```
docker logs zabbix-server-mysql
```

i found this messages

```
autoregistration from "172.17.0.1" denied (host:"cb6b283d07ce" ip:"172.17.0.1" port:10050): connection type "TLS with PSK" is not allowed for autoregistration
209:20230308:134017.006 cannot send list of active checks to "172.17.0.1": host [cb6b283d07ce] not found
```

Any idea please to solve this issue ??

Thank you

Comment: Hostname must be the agent's hostname, not the container's.

Comment: @IronBishop thanks for your response, how i can find the agent's Hostname ? bcz i tried to use the server's Hostname and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple,

I had to use the container hostname
but I forgot to put it on the zabbix interface too

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should write the ip address of zabbix agent down into interface section.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set environment variable ZBX_HOSTNAME to be the same as in the configuration, e.g. `ZBX_HOSTNAME="Zabbix server"`.
Ref: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407079/2699490) , [2](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-troubleshooting-and-problems/413355-zabbix-agent-no-active-checks-on-server?p=413401#post413401)